# WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID not binding to input field value ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this page.html:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)" class="list">
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>SSID</ion-label>
<ion-input name="ssid" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="currentSSID"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
<ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
<ion-input name="passwd" ngModel type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>SSID Hidden?</ion-label>
  <ion-select name="notHidden" ngModel>
  <ion-option value="NO">NO</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="YES">YES</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Device
      <ion-icon name="md-add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>   
</form>
```

And in my ts file I have this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var WifiWizard;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-device',
  templateUrl: 'add-device.html'
})
export class AddDevicePage {

value: any;
currentSSID: string; 
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams , public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public platform:Platform) {
WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(this.ssidHandler, this.fail);
  }
ssidHandler(s) {
    alert(s)
    this.currentSSID=s;
}
fail(e){
    alert("Please connect to your local WIFI ");
} 
}
```

I really cant figure out why isn't the this.currentSSID=s putting the ssid value in the input field...
If I go and place this: this.currentSSID='testing 123' in the beginning of the constructor it is binding to the ssid input field.

Comment: If you get s value in your alert(), then something wrong with the scope of this. i mean when you using this.currentSSID(the way you used it) this do not refer to AddDevicePage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this way :

Instead of declaring the handler functions as part of the class can you create them as local functions and try the same : 
Inside your constructor :

```
WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);//removed 'this'
function ssidHandler(s) {//declare inside the constructor locally
    alert(s)
    this.currentSSID=s;
}
function fail(e){//declare inside the constructor locally
    alert("Please connect to your local WIFI ");
}
```

EDIT : Something to do with the scope of 'this'.
Solution : `var self = this;//in the constructor outside of the callback functions` and Inside the `ssidHandler(), self.currentSSID = s;`

Comment: Still same result. I get the "s" in the alert but it is not binds to the "this.currentSSID". I need to mention that "WifiWizard" is a cordova plugin.

Comment: no it is just not binding to currentSSID. if I put this line:  this.currentSSID="yyy";        before this : WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);  it is binding so I dont understand...

Comment: maybe callbackContext of cordova plugin just supposed to act like this?

Comment: why are you populating it in the <ion-input> tag? You want it to be editable?

Comment: Yes but I tried also to put it as text or label and it is still not binding...do you  have a suggestion?

Comment: Ummm.. probably something to do with the scope of 'this'. Okay.. can you try this? Put var self = this;//in the constructor outside of the callback functions and Inside the ssidHandler(), self.currentSSID = s;

Comment: OK so the self thing did make a progress now it is binding but for some reason it is with  Apostrophes but this is something easy to fix programmatic...thanks